# What would i do if i want to access the data in upside 3-4 folders using import export method

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, export

I want to access the data in folders which are 3-4 folders upside and i don't know how how to get the data without changing the location of any file.
[Here the location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwP5Z.png)
In this image i want to access the data and export it from data.js and import it into app.js.

I try many things like methods such as "../" but can't get reached to that location. So, I'm expecting to get the location to get the data by using import export method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative routes.

Your app.js file is in the javascript folder. Then, you first have to go to the public folder and, lastly, to your main project folder. Where your data is.

So, you must jump two levels back by doing "**../../data.js**".